# I want to take user input in regular expression in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

Below is my code.

```py
import pandas as pd

import re

text = "monotonous monumental  Hello friday monoclonal"

mon = input('please write first three letters which you want to find ? ')

Number = int(input('please write how many number you want to extract after three letters ? '))

pattern = re.compile(mon+'\w{Number}') #here in place of '{Number}' I want to use user input

match = pattern.findall(text)

print(match)
```

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import re
text = "monotonous monumental Hello friday monoclonal"
mon = input('please write first three letters which you want to find ? ')
pattern = re.compile(mon+'\w{4}')#here in place of 'mon' I want to use user input
match = pattern.findall(text)
print(match)
```

This should work.